# Will a self balancing wing using an Eppler 186 airfoil still generate a Clmax of about 3+ with slats and slotted flaps?

Tags: aerodynamics

Will a self balancing wing using an Eppler 186 airfoil still generate a cl of about 3+ with slats and slotted flaps?

Although the NACA2415 used in the pegasus wing for the Zenith 701 has a low Cm, the Eppler 186 has an almost zero Cm at an AOA of about 3 deg.

Just wondering if there is some aerodynamic reason why it couldn't generate a Clmax of about 3, the same as the NACA2415?

Of course, it would only be self balancing in cruise, without the slats and flaps deployed.

I understand not all airfoils see the same increase in Clmax, due to the leading edge, etc.

Comment: Do you mean, can slats and slotted flaps when deployed not overly affect Cm?

Comment: Are you designing a flying wing? Otherwise, why would you be using a reflex airfoil for your main wing?

Comment: @Jimmy Perhaps to minimize/eliminate trim drag?  He'll need an empennage when the flaps and slats are out, but in cruise, that could be trimmed to zero lift, zero alpha and produce only its form drag (which can be pretty danged small).

Comment: My design is a biplane with a 10' span with folding wings and a 10' Lv. I understand the Lazair had a very short Lv and used a double reflex wing.  So I'm trying to minimize my horizontal tail area by using a reflex wing as my Lv is so short. Think Bumblebee. Is this thinking correct? Works pretty good in XFLR5!!

Comment: @ZeissIkon Trim drag may be small potato compared to the efficiency loss by choosing a reflex airfoil. The CLmax loss alone decreases performance. And you can only get zero-lift on tail for a single design point at a single speed.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, a single point, which would be your cruise speed which is about 90% of the time, no?

Comment: If you stagger your upper vs. lower wing, you can use relative incidence to do what that reflex airfoil would, and (I think) with less loss of efficiency.  You'll probably still need a pitch surface when your flaps/slats are out, though.

Comment: @Fred I don't know your particular design objective, but most of the time no. Unless you have a single weight, CG, speed, altitude you'll be flying all the time.